# Perform login and logout in android

Tags: android

In my application, after the user registers or logs in, to stay in the session until that person logs out. I found that some people are talking about using sharedPreferences for this,  but I didn't really know how to use it to accomplish this!

How can I use sharedPreferences in order to manage login/logout?

Comment: +1 - I see what you were asking now, so I edited to clean up the grammar a bit. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some starter code to help you:

```
public String getStringPreference(String key) {
            return settings.getString(key,  null); 
    }

    public void setStringPreference(String key, String value) {

        settings.edit().putString(key, value).commit();

    }
```

In your Activity's or Application's onCreate, call this:

```
settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Where settings is defined in your class as:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
```

What SharedPreferences are, are in a way like cookies for web pages.  They allow you to store small pieces of information for a long time, using a key/value store (basically "something"="somevalue");

Upon successful validation of a user's credentials (you'd likely have a login activity of some sort), you would store their username and/or hashed password or token in shared preferences.  If you call getStringPreference("userId") and it doesn't come back null, then you are logged in (You need something more robust than that, but that's a start).